# adding "http" and "com/in" dynamically into the addressbar in UIViewin iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a adressbar(textfiled) which is linked to UIView. I want say if I type "google" into the addressbar and press search(UIButton) then "http" and "com" will add dynamically into the addressbar. Write now I am passing "http" and 'com" with my code, But I want these things to be autogenerated at the runtime when user click the Seacrh(UIButton). Please tell me how to do this. I am posting my code below:-

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hi");
    NSString *http= @"http://";
    addressbar.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",http,addressbar.text,@".com"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:addressbar.text];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.web.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.web loadRequest:request];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hi");
    NSString *http= @"http://";
    NSString *com= @".com";
    NSURL *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",http,addressbar.text,com];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.web.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.web loadRequest:request];
addressbar.text=url;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say but I your code and mine code both are same. My prob is that suppose for the first time I typed only google then (http:// and .com are adding to it beacuse i have passed these things in my code and it goes displayed in addressbar).suppose If I am typing full address(www.google.com) then in this case 'http' and 'com' are adding into my addresstext which i dont want to. Therefore i am looking soln for this.

Comment: try to remove strings of www and .com if they exists in text box